# Is there a way to see when the Azure Functions Runtime was updated?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-functions-runtime

We started seeing some new errors in one of our functions in relation to a DryIoc accessing a disposed Singleton object. There are several posts suggesting to set the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` to a specific version. I can see in the Azure Portal that our runtime is currently set [2.0.13759.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.13759) which was released on June 1, 2020. There have been a few more releases since that time, which leads me to my question. I'm not necessarily saying it is the cause of our issue, but how can I tell when a consumption plan's runtime was updated?

Comment: When a minor version is available to update and no breaking changes, it will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update Answer:**

If you just want to know when the runtime update instead of notify you know when update, it is possiable.

Please follow these steps:

1, Use this url in your browser to go to the kudu of your function app:

```
https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole
```

2, Click Debug Console -> CMD, and then Go to LogFiles/eventlog.xml, it will store the update time of the runtime. The structure is like below:

[image]

This can only meet your needs of seeing the update time, but can not notify you. The notify system of azure function dont have this event.

**Original Answer:**

`FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` is used to specify the language your function is using. I think what you are talking about is `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION`.

This doc talks about the update of the function app runtime version update:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version#automatic-and-manual-version-updates

This a built-in feature, it will not notify you. If you only give the major runtime version, it will update automatically when a minor version is available to update and no breaking changes. If you want to avoid this, you can set the `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` as the minor version instead of major version like `~2`. If you do that, it will not update automatically.

Comment: Yes, the `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` is what I'm looking for. Is there a way to find out when it was updated automatically?

Comment: @scottrudy Yes, of course. If you just want to know when the runtime update instead of notify you know when update, it is possiable. I will update in my answer.

Comment: Same question asked for Linux here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427601/is-there-a-way-to-see-when-the-azure-functions-runtime-was-updated-in-linux