# Is there a way to see when the Azure Functions Runtime was updated in Linux?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-functions-runtime

For an Azure Function, how can I tell when an Azure App Service Plan's `FUNCTION_EXTENSION_VERSION` was updated on a Linux server?

Note this is in relation to the same exact question [answered for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62410187/is-there-a-way-to-see-when-the-azure-functions-runtime-was-updated).

Comment: I checked all the log files in the physical path, and also used the monitor to monitor the behavior of the function app, but none of this information was recorded. For Linux-based function apps, you may not be able to do it, because this information is not recorded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For an Azure Function, how can I tell when an Azure App Service Plan's
> FUNCTION_EXTENSION_VERSION was updated on a Linux server?

Linux azure function is different from windows azure function. Their design methods are different. I first tried to use ftp and connected to the physical path to view the log information recorded therein. After manually changing the runtime version, I checked all the log files, but none of them stored relevant information. Then I used Azure Monitor to monitor the behavior of the function app, and there was still no record. I think for the linux-based function app, your needs cannot be fulfilled temporarily, because the function app itself does not record it as information at all...